# Streaming video in real-time using a gstreamer-rtsp server to a web page

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, gstreamer

I am trying to build an application that can consume a video source(could be from a webcam or an offline video) and stream it in real-time to a web-page. I have been successful in creating a rtsp stream using gstreamer, but I am unable to receive this stream on the web page without an intermediate step i.e. converting the stream to a playlist.m3u8 using hlssink or ffmpeg.

I want the stream to be directly consumed by the web-page. Also, Is using the vlc-plugin my only option?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

RTSP is not going to work over browser because most browsers do not support direct RTP streaming. If for some reason HTTP adaptive streaming protocols like HLS are not satisfying your requirements (e.g. latency not low enough), you can try WebRTC which is among others built on top of secure RTP (SRTP). It has a probably more involved setup than an RTSP server but is nowadays supported by all major browsers. You can check out the [webrtcbin](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/webrtc/index.html?gi-language=c) element for a GStreamer implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it's possible since RTSP is not supported by any browser directly, and plugins support was removed by most of the modern browsers.
So the only solution is do conversion from RTSP to some supported by browsers format.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments! I was able to make this work using Gstreamer's WebRTC example from : https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-examples/-/tree/master/webrtc.

Comment: Just to clarify, you still need an intermediate step, if the camera is sending RTSP then the browser can play HLS and WebRTC so you’ll need something to convert it. Gstreamer speaks RTSP and WebRTC so will speak to your camera and then to your browser browser as long as you jump through the hoops of SDP exchange and ICE candidates exchange.